# Проблема с функцией в регулярном выражении[manking]

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Странно, что нельзя добавлять комментарии к старой теме. Начну по новой.

[@manking](/users/7538/manking), ты просил код $page_result. Вот он:

```
ifcodes(123 == 124)
```

Сама регулярка:

```
echo preg_replace('/ifcodes\((.*?)\)/i', ifcodes("$1"), $page_result);
```

Функция ifcodes():

```
function ifcodes($a) {
 if($a) return 'OK';
}
```

То есть в ifcodes("$1") должно заноситься то, что вырезано из регулярки. В данном случае 123 == 124. В функции прописать если: return $a; , то оно выведет то, что нам нужно, т.е 123 == 124. Но при задании условия:

```
if($a)
```

оно будто не срабатывает. Всегда показывает, что истинно. А ведь на самом деле 123 != 124..

Comment: Потому что у тебя в функцию заносится не результат регулярного выражения, а СТРОКА STRING.
Вот вставь это в  ifcodes
echo "<br>a=" . $a;
echo "<br><br>тип переменной=" . gettype($a);// здесь будет тип string

Comment: @manking, не всё понял. Вы можете по порядку объяснить, что мне нужно сделать, чтобы всё заработало?

Comment: Для начала надо понять что вы хотите.

Вы хотите найти условное выражения в строке
"текст(123 == 124)"
 типа
123==124

И если они верные, то заменять всё это выражение 123==111 на какое то новое значение?


Вот так вот
"текст(НЕ_РАВНО)"
??
Если нет то подробно объясните.

Comment: $manking, смотрите. "ifcodes(123 == 124)" отсюда нужно вырезать то, что в круглых скобках. Это я сделал. То есть вырежет 123 == 124. После чего заменить это всё на функцию ifcodes($a). $a должно быть - вырезенное из скобок, то есть 123 == 124. Вообщем в самой функции мне нужно прописать условие, если $a(всё, что в круглых скобках) истинно, то return 'OK'. Просто я пытаюсь написать свой шаблонизатор, основу написал, а вот теперь практикуюсь на условниках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем я как не понимал, так и не понимаю.
Если в PHP куда то как то в preg_replace() передаётся указатель на ifcodes(), то объясните мне.

Вот это выражение:
ifcodes("$1")

- Срабатывает только 1 раз!
- То есть функция ifcodes(){}
     вызывается 1 раз.
- ifcodes() вызывается до вызова
     preg_replace()
- preg_replace() не вызывает ifcodes()
     по ходу своего выполнения.
- preg_replace() не знает о
     существовании ifcodes()
- preg_replace() во втором аргументе
     принимает не указатель на функцию
     ifcodes(), а результат её работы.
- preg__replace(... , 'OK' , ...) - во 2 аргумент попадает 'OK', в момент старта функции preg_replace()

Чтобы получить качественный ответ, надо внимательно проанализировать что вы хотите.
Укажите полностью

- входную строку
- требуемый результат, что должно оказаться здесь $page_result в конце программы?